# Laptop battery won't charge (0%), is it damaged?

Tags: laptop, battery, power

My laptop battery won't charge anymore, sits at 0%, and the laptop only operates if plugged to the AC adapter (it detects the power cord, but charge remains at 0%)
The battery is already 2.5 years old, saw extensive use (at least daily recharge). so I wouldn't be surprised if it is damaged/beyond repair, but could it just be a software issue? I'm running Arch Linux.

Comment: Can the bios report any info re the battery? Number of cycles , original capacity, current capacity, whether connected and recognised...

Comment: In Mac, I know you can generate battery reports using the ioreg command.  ArchLinux probably has a similar command.

Comment: It's likely dead, *but* a common reason for this is that the charging of cells in series has become imbalanced. I've split the case for a 3-cell battery and found that *one* of the type-18650 cells was discharged, but two others were fully charged. Putting the discharged cell in a one-cell charger fixed the issue. *Caveat:* a mistake here could cause fire or explosion.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a dead battery. If you are charging the device round the clock, it's highly likely that the battery will go out the window 2 years in.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.